# Attr in my iframe pdf

Tags: jquery, attr

I'm using Html2Pdf which permit me to generate a PDF.
It's working correctly, i want to add my iframe before my jquery and set the attribut src after.

I have that :

```
success: function (data) {
            $("#loader99").hide();
            $(".show_pdf_vcmd").append('<iframe id="fullFrame" src="temp/' + data.pdfurl_vcmd_ajax + '.pdf "width="50%" height="700px" class="pdf"></iframe>') 
            }

 <div class="show_pdf_vcmd"></div>
```

I want to have this result :

```
success: function (data) {
                $("#loader99").hide();
              // Here put the attribut src (with my data) in .show_pdf_vcmd
                }

<div class="show_pdf_vcmd"><iframe id="fullFrame" width="50%" height="700px" class="pdf"></iframe></div>
```

Thanks how can i do it ?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) I don't understand what you are wanting to accomplish.

Comment: Add a semicolon at the end of the line in which you are appending the iframe-tag. It should be working – what is your current, erronous output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [$.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
success: function (data) {
          $("#loader99").hide();
           $("#fullFrame").attr("src","temp/'" + data.pdfurl_vcmd_ajax + "'.pdf");
   }

<div class="show_pdf_vcmd"><iframe id="fullFrame" width="50%" height="700px" class="pdf"></iframe></div>
```

You need to ensure that the `success` function is triggered after the DOM is ready. It means the function the call an ajax should be inside `$(document).ready` to avoid timing problem.